# Is there a way to request permission again when it has been blocked by Chrome in a Flutter web app?

Tags: flutter, web, permissions, progressive-web-apps, permission-denied

**If the user blocks permission for the first time, I want to grant permission again.**

For example, if a user blocks location permission for a Flutter web app, the web app will not be able to access the user's location information. Similarly, if a user blocks microphone permission for a web app, the web app will not be able to access the user's microphone.

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter, handling permissions and opening app settings works differently on the web compared to mobile platforms. On web platforms, you typically can't programmatically open the browser's site settings where users would enable permissions. Instead, you need to guide the user through the process.

You can use kIsWeb to check if you are in the web. If so then you can show an alert which tells the user to configure permsissions in the browser settings. If you are on mobile, then you can show an Alert with a button leading to AppSettings.

Also dont forget that for opening an Alert after an async command, which a permission request usually is, you should use a context saved before the async function is called since it could be that the context becomes invalid.